# Can't see the first property of a node on Age Viewer

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

I have created a Book node called Book as follow:

```
Select * FROM cypher('graph_two',$$ CREATE (n:Book {title:'Something'}) $$) as (a agtype);
```

And a person Node as follows:

```
Select * FROM cypher('graph_two',$$ CREATE (n:User {Name:'Something'}) $$) as (a agtype);
```

And an edge between them as follows:

```
Select * FROM cypher('graph_two',$$ MATCH (a:User), (b:Book) CREATE (a)-[r:READS]->(b) Return r $$) as (r agtype);
```

And when I visualize this in age-viewer I get:
[image]

What am I doing wrong here? I want the User name and the Book title to be displayed rather than the OId.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click on any Node Label (your's are "Book" and "User") it will appear a bar on the bottom of the current graph scene. There you can set what the vertex or edge is currently displaying, the size of the vertex and also the color of them. This also works with the edges.

[image]